# How to execute 'top' Command output using Golang

Tags: go

I want to write the 'top' command's output to another file. But when I tried it with the below code, I get the below error:

'exit status 1'.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import "os/exec"

func main() {
    app := "top"
    cmd := exec.Command(app)
    stdout, err := cmd.Output()

    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    print(string(stdout))
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From man page for "top", -b option is good for sending output to another program (no color, no anything) as plain text, and -n is the number of frame it will iterate before stopping. Without -n it will iterate infinite time.

```
 func main() {
      app := "top"
      arg0 := "-b"
      arg1 := "-n"
      arg2 := "1"

      cmd := exec.Command(app, arg0, arg1, arg2)
      stdout, err := cmd.Output()

      if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
        return
      }

      print(string(stdout))
    }
```

Comment: Hi Boris Le Méec, thanks for the response. Inside Xen Server, I'm trying to run 'xentop' command instead of 'top' command. But there is no response for 'xentop' command. Also how to run another Binary File inside Go Lang program?

Comment: I don't know Xen Server or xentop, but from the man page or `xentop`, you should use `-b` and `-i` for the number of iteration.

If you want to run a binary file inside go it's the same thing, just use `exec.Command(path_to_binary).Output()` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
s := fmt.Sprintf(`"top -bn2 | fgrep 'Cpu(s)' | tail -1"`, host)
log.Printf("top = %s\n", s)
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", s)
b, e := cmd.Output()
if e != nil {
    log.Printf("failed due to :%v\n", e)
    panic(e)
}
log.Printf("%v\n", string(b))
raw := string(b)
```

This is what you could potentially do if you are planning to run top in batch mode. Note tail -1 maybe of value if you wanted to pick last one instead of capturing everything, and fgrep useful if you are to grep for a specific fields - however it is not necessary.

For reference, here are other ways to run top.

```
c := exec.Command("top")
c.Stdin = os.Stdin
c.Stdout = os.Stdout
c.Stderr = os.Stderr
c.Run()
```

This is for local. If you are looking via ssh, use this -

```
c := exec.Command("ssh", "-t", "localhost", "top")
c.Stdin = os.Stdin
c.Stdout = os.Stdout
c.Stderr = os.Stderr
c.Run()
```

If you want to start a server, and connect as a client via telnet and show on telnet screen result of top command (common case when running top remotely using a go introspecting server perhaps) use this -

```
    func main() {
        l, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:12345")
        for {
            c, _ := l.Accept()
            go func() {
                handle(&c)
            }()
        }
    }
    func handle(c *net.Conn) {
        cmd := exec.Command("top")
        cstdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
        go io.Copy(bufio.NewWriter(*c), bufio.NewReader(cstdout))
        cmd.Run()
    }
```

If you are building a terminal using telnet and ssh to run generic commands like app use this library - https://github.com/kr/pty

**Edit** Going to make it better ... here's an example that works for PTY, scenario is if you use ssh -t to run a command want to interact with telneting from this server type setup e.g. top use this :

```
       cmd := exec.Command("ssh", "-t", "localhost", "top")
        f, _ := pty.Start(cmd)
        go io.Copy(bufio.NewWriter(*c), f)
        go io.Copy(f, bufio.NewReader(*c))
        go io.Copy(bufio.NewWriter(*c), os.Stdin)
        cmd.Run()
```